# HTML live editor for angular

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, visual-studio, google-chrome-extension

hi I search for extension for ive editing html code angular without recompiling it

Answer (score 1):

Because Angular transform the whole projekt into a SPA (Single-Page App) which include the html and javascript too in a bundle, you need to compile it, if you want to test your changes. 'ng serve'  command does it for you. The compile time depends a lot on the performance of your machine.
Of course you can still make changes on html and css in the browser for testing.:)